# How to use python file included in aws lambda layers inside aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to use the python library [fgsect/scat](https://github.com/fgsect/scat) inside my aws lambda function. I have created a zip file with this library and set it as a lambda layer. I am looking for the correct way to call the python file scat.py with arguments.

e.g

```
python3 ./scat.py -t qc -d log.qmdl -F log.pcap
```

Things I have tried so far.

I have created the lambda layer with the following file structure

```
python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

and below is what I have in the lambda handler

```
import os
import scat

os.system("scat.py -t qc -d log.qmdl -F log.pcap")
```

This did not work (gives an error "sh: scat.py: command not found")

I am planning to use ephemeral storage to store both log.qmdl and log.pcap. Does anyone know how to use this library correctly with arguments inside the aws lambda function?

Comment: Why are you trying to run it via a shell command?

Comment: I am a bit new to python. Is there a different way to run it?

Comment: I am confused because this python3 ./scat.py -t qc -d log.qmdl -F log.pcap is the command that works. And this scat.py is inside the lambda layer

Comment: I imagine `scat.py` will have a `main` function, just run that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500228

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks