# Installing geodjango on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, geodjango

I would like to use geodjango, but the error that I am getting when following the official installation guide is:

```
File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I see that this error has been addressed here
[OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) but I still don't know how to fix it in this case. Do I have to make some change to that line?

Comment: Please enter the command you have executed to triger this error and the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the file is corrupted. Try downloading from an alternate server or a different site. Or use command line to install it

Comment: Well I tried all that but got nowhere, so I just switched over to Linux. Thanks for trying.