# Unable to resolve OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

I tried to run the python code on command line .I facing error `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`.

I am new to python clang wrapper functions.
I am using python 3.7.2 of 32 bit.
I am using llvm of 64 bit of version 7.1.0.

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python   
    import sys
    import clang.cindex
    import ctypes
    clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path('C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin')



    print("argument1   ------> ",sys.argv[1])
    print("argument2   ------> ",sys.argv[2])


    def find_typerefs(node, typename):

        if node.kind.is_reference():
            ref_node = node.get_definition()
            if ref_node.spelling == typename:
                print( 'Found %s [line=%s, col=%s]' % (
                    typename, node.location.line, node.location.column))
        # Recurse for children of this node
        for c in node.get_children():
            find_typerefs(c, typename)




    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()




    tu = index.parse(sys.argv[1])
    print( 'Translation unit:', tu.spelling)
    find_typerefs(tu.cursor, sys.argv[2])
```

I tried with subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'parser.py', 'dummyC++.cpp','person'],shell=True) and getting same error

```
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 4129, in get_cindex_library
    library = cdll.LoadLibrary(self.get_filename())
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 30, in <module>
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 2666, in create
    return Index(conf.lib.clang_createIndex(excludeDecls, 0))
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 198, in __get__
    value = self.wrapped(instance)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 4103, in lib
    lib = self.get_cindex_library()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 4134, in get_cindex_library
    raise LibclangError(msg)
clang.cindex.LibclangError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. To provide a path to libclang use Config.set_library_path() or Config.set_library_file().
```

This is the error message

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: @ frankegoesdown tried that solutions.but still facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Install 32 bit version of llvm from this(http://releases.llvm.org/download.html)
make sure 32 bit version of python is installed.
and everything works fine.