# Error while importing modules on anaconda spyder

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I get an error while importing modules.

import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import numpy as np

File "C:\Users\girik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import core

File "C:\Users\girik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 23, in 
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

File "C:\Users\girik\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 356, in **init**
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: do you have an additional python installation on your machine, besides the one that comes with anaconda? EDIT: checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) Q&A for the error?

Comment: You should reinstall Python to fix this problem. And to avoid this kind of problems, I'd suggest to switch to Anaconda instead.