# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application while running numpy library on Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder

When I'm trying to import the numpy library on Spyder (anaconda), this is the error I get:

```
    import numpy as np

  File "C:\Users\ndabouz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init

  File "C:\Users\ndabouz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Users\ndabouz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I tried to uninstall and install python, ananconda and numpy library.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you see this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: If you have Anaconda installed, then the above error means you installed numpy with pip, which is terrible because it creates this kind of conflicts. To fix please remove this directory: `C:\Users\ndabouz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\`.

Comment: Thkank you very much @CarlosCordoba ! It worked !! :)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba that sounds like it would make a good answer with a little explanation of why it works (and perhaps why it is safe).