# Error with import PIL (Pillow) in 32 and 64 bit Python

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I have two python versions installed for some reason: 3.7.7 32-bit and 3.7.8 64-bit. The specific line `from PIL import Image` brings different errors. In 64-bit, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "equinox.py", line 20, in <module>
        from PIL import Image, ImageOps,ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
      File "C:\Users\FAMILY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageEnhance.py", line 21, in <module>
        from . import Image, ImageFilter, ImageStat
      File "C:\Users\FAMILY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageFilter.py", line 20, in <module>
        import numpy
      File "C:\Users\FAMILY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
        from . import _distributor_init
      File "C:\Users\FAMILY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
        WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
      File "C:\Users\FAMILY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

and in 32-bit I get this error: `ImportError: cannot import _imaging from PIL` when it tries `from . import _imaging as core`.

I tried fixing both problems by reinstalling Python, reinstalling Pillow, deleting leftover PIL folders, checking for any files in the directory that is named `_imaging` `PIL` `Pillow` `Image` but nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: in every version you should install different version of `pillow`. If you don't have separated `pip` for both Pythons then you should use `python -m pip install pillow` for both versions

Comment: I tried, still doesnt work. I get `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\family\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (7.2.0)`

Comment: if you have two Pythons installed then you have to install `pillow` also two times - and you have to use different `python` - `path/to/32bit/python -m pip install pillow` and `path/to/64bit/python -m pip install pillow`.

Comment: it says requirement already satisfied in both version

Comment: I have no idea what is problem

Comment: Does this question address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028071/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-while-running-numpy

Comment: sadly it doesnt @Weeble