# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, oserror

I have been trying a simple code on Pycharm 2019.2.1 on Windows 10 64-bit:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df = pd.read_csv('covid_19_clean_complete.csv')
X = df[["Deaths"]]
Y = df["Confirmed"]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.25, random_state=42)
acr = LinearRegression()    
acr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
print(acr.score(X_test,Y_test))
```

but it is showing me this error:

[image: error message]

I've already uninstalled pandas once and installed again using

```
pip uninstall pandas 
pip install pandas
```

[image: pandas installed photo]

[image: Interpreter photo]

I searched but the links I found, were not clear to me.

Here's one of the search results:
[OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Comment: have you defined the python interpreter for your project on pycharms?

Comment: Architecture mismatch. You installed the wrong *NumPy* package (probably installed it manually, as *PIP* correctly selects it). Might check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745 for more details about the error.

Comment: Mr. @CristiFati, thank you for the link, but I was wondering how can I check if dll is 32 or 64? The python is 64. also, how can I change from 32 to 64.
Thank You

Comment: Mr. @RajatMishra I've defined in pycharm, not in the project. But, should it make any difference? Because I've defined the path.
Before this problem, it used to work well.


Already I have created an environment in the project folder, still problem remains.

Comment: For the *.dll*, you can use *Dependency Walker*. For *Python*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os/50053286#50053286. You can install both *Python* versions.

Comment: Well, I just uninstalled python, PyCharm and all other relevant files from C drive. Then again installed them with modules. Now working pretty well. Though it is not the best way to solve it. 

Answer (score -1):

Finally, all I did was uninstall Pycharm and Python from my system. Then again re-installed them. Then the problem was solved.