# Deploying EKS cluster using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, boto3

I already have a .py file. While I deploy the .py file, eks clusters and node groups will get created.
While running the following python script I am getting the following error :

**OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

##############################################################################
#
# Create a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using EKS.  You should know that this
# takes an absolute age, allow 20-30 mins.  That's just the speed stuff
# deploys at.
#
# This assumes that kubectl and heptio-authenticator-aws are in your PATH.
#
# This script works incrementally.  It creates things in sequence, and assumes
# that if they already exist, they're good.  If you get things breaking
# during deployment, you'll want to make sure you don't have something
# broken.
#
##############################################################################

import boto3
import boto3.ec2
import sys
import json
import time
import yaml
import subprocess
import os

############################################################################
# Config you might want to change
############################################################################

# AWS Region
region = "ap-south-1"

# Cluster name
cluster_name = "MyEksCluster"

# K8s version to deploy
k8s_version = "1.18"

# Size of cluster.
node_group_min = 2
node_group_max = 5

# Worker instance types to deploy
instance_type = "t2.medium"

############################################################################
# Config you might not want to change
############################################################################

# Names for VPC and worker stack
vpc_name = cluster_name + "-vpc"
workers_name = cluster_name + "-workers"

# CloudFormation templates for VPC and worker nodes
vpc_template = "https://myeksfiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/vpc-2public-2private-subnets.yaml"
workers_template = "https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.10.3/2018-06-05/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml"

# K8s IAM role name to use
k8s_admin_role_name = "MyEksadminRole"

# Config file to write kubectl configuration to.
config_file = "C:\\Users\\Hari\\PycharmProjects\\python_Project\\.kube\\kubeconfig.yaml"

# Keypair for accessing workers.  Keypair name and filename.
keypair_name = "kd"
secret_file = "secret.pem"

# Image names for AMIs providing workers.
node_images = {
    "ap-south-1": "ami-08f63db601b82ff5f",
    "us-east-1": "ami-04d29b6f966df1537"
}

# Filename to write internal auth thing to.
worker_auth = "aws-auth-cm.yaml"

############################################################################
# Connect AWS
############################################################################

# Connect to AWS, EC2, cloudformation, IAM and EKS
s = boto3.Session(region_name=region)
ec2 = s.client("ec2")
cf = s.client("cloudformation")
iam = s.client("iam")
eks = s.client("eks")

############################################################################
# IAM role for K8s
############################################################################

print("*** IAM role")

try:

    # See if role exists.
    role = iam.get_role(RoleName=k8s_admin_role_name)
    print("IAM role exists.")

except:

    print("IAM role does not exist.  Creating...")

    # This is an AWS role policy document.  Allows access for EKS.
    policy_doc = json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    # Create role.
    iam.create_role(
        RoleName=k8s_admin_role_name,
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument=policy_doc,
        Description="Role providing access to EKS resources from EKS"
    )

    print( "Role created.")
    print( "Attaching policies...")

    # Add policies allowing access to EKS API.

    iam.attach_role_policy(
        RoleName=k8s_admin_role_name,
        PolicyArn="arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
    )

    iam.attach_role_policy(
        RoleName=k8s_admin_role_name,
        PolicyArn="arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
    )

    print("Attached.")

# Get role ARN for later.
role = iam.get_role(RoleName=k8s_admin_role_name)
role_arn = role["Role"]["Arn"]


############################################################################
# VPC stack
############################################################################

# The VPC stack is a VPC and subnetworks to allow K8s communication.

# Check if a stack exists.
def stack_exists(cf, name):
    try:
        stack = cf.describe_stacks(StackName=name)
        return True
    except:
        return False


print("*** VPC stack")
if stack_exists(cf, vpc_name):

    # If stack exists, do nothing.
    print("VPC stack already exists")

else:

    print("Creating VPC stack...")

    # Create VPC stack.
    response = cf.create_stack(
        StackName=vpc_name,
        TemplateURL=vpc_template,
        Parameters=[],
        TimeoutInMinutes=15,
        OnFailure='DELETE'
    )

    if response == None:
        print("Could not create VPC stack")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not "StackId" in response:
        print("Could not create VPC stack")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Get stack ID for later.
    stack_id = response["StackId"]

    print("Created stack " + vpc_name)
    print("Waiting for VPC stack creation to complete...")

    try:

        # A waiter is something which polls AWS to find out if an operation
        # has completed.
        waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')

        # Wait for stack creation to complet
        res = waiter.wait(
            StackName=vpc_name,
        )

    except:

        # If waiter fails, that'll be the thing taking too long to deploy.
        print("Gave up waiting for stack to create")
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Stack created")

# Get output information from the stack: VPC ID, security group and subnet IDs.
stack = cf.describe_stacks(StackName=vpc_name)
vpc_sg = None
vpc_subnet_ids = None
vpc_id = None

# Loop over outputs grabbing information.
for v in stack["Stacks"][0]["Outputs"]:
    if v["OutputKey"] == "SecurityGroups":
        vpc_sg = v["OutputValue"]
    if v["OutputKey"] == "VpcId":
        vpc_id = v["OutputValue"]
    if v["OutputKey"] == "SubnetIds":
        vpc_subnet_ids = v["OutputValue"]

print("VPC ID: %s" % vpc_id)
print("VPC security group: %s" % vpc_sg)
print("VPC subnet IDs: %s" % vpc_subnet_ids)

# Split subnet IDs - it's comma separated.
vpc_subnet_ids = vpc_subnet_ids.split(",")

############################################################################
# EKS cluster
############################################################################

print("*** EKS cluster")

try:
    cluster = eks.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)
    print("Cluster already exists.")

except:

    print("Creating cluster (ETA ~10 minutes)...")

    # Create Kubernetes cluster.
    response = eks.create_cluster(
        name=cluster_name,
        version=k8s_version,
        roleArn=role_arn,
        resourcesVpcConfig={
            "subnetIds": vpc_subnet_ids,
            "securityGroupIds": [vpc_sg]
        }
    )

    print("Cluster creation initiated.")
    "Cluster creation initiated."
    print("Waiting for completion (ETA 10 minutes)...")

    # Wait for two minutes before doing the checking.
    time.sleep(120)

    # Going to give up after 40 times 20 seconds.  Btw, EKS API / boto3 doesn't
    # currently support a 'waiter' object to wait for the cluster to start,
    # which would be nice.
    i = 40
    while True:

        # Wait 20 seconds
        time.sleep(20)

        try:

            # Get cluster status
            cluster = eks.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)
            status = cluster["cluster"]["status"]

            print("Cluster status: %s" % status)

            # Is it active? If so break out of loop
            if status == "ACTIVE":
                break

            # Maybe give up after so many goes.
            i = i - 1
            if i <= 0:
                print("Given up waiting for cluster to go ACTIVE.")
                sys.exit(1)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception:", e)

    print("Cluster active.")

# Get cluster stuff
cluster = eks.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)

# This spots the case where the cluster isn't in an expected state.
status = cluster["cluster"]["status"]
if status != "ACTIVE":
    print("Cluster status %s, should be ACTIVE!" % status)
    sys.exit(1)

# Get cluster endpoint and security info.
cluster_cert = cluster["cluster"]["certificateAuthority"]["data"]
cluster_ep = cluster["cluster"]["endpoint"]

print("Cluster: %s" % cluster_ep)

############################################################################
# K8s config
############################################################################

print("*** EKS configuration")

# This section creates a Kubernetes kubectl configuration file if one does
# not exist.

if os.path.isfile(config_file):
    print("Config exists already.")
else:

    cluster_config = {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Config",
        "clusters": [
            {
                "cluster": {
                    "server": str(cluster_ep),
                    "certificate-authority-data": str(cluster_cert)
                },
                "name": "kubernetes"
            }
        ],
        "contexts": [
            {
                "context": {
                    "cluster": "kubernetes",
                    "user": "aws"
                },
                "name": "aws"
            }
        ],
        "current-context": "aws",
        "preferences": {},
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "aws",
                "user": {
                    "exec": {
                        "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1",
                        "command": "heptio-authenticator-aws",
                        "args": [
                            "token", "-i", cluster_name
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    # Write in YAML.
    config_text = yaml.dump(cluster_config, default_flow_style=False)
    open(config_file, "w").write(config_text)

    print("Written to %s." % config_file)

    # Having written the kubectl configuration, should check it works...
    print("Try kubectl command...")

    resp = subprocess.call(["kubectl", "--kubeconfig=%s" % config_file, "get",
                            "nodes"])

    if resp != 0:
        print("The kubectl command didn't work.")
        sys.exit(1)

    print("All working.")

############################################################################
# Keypair for workers
############################################################################

print("*** Keypairs")

try:

    # Check if keypair exists, if not, ignore this step.
    key = ec2.describe_key_pairs(
        KeyNames=[keypair_name]
    )

    print("Keypair exists.")

except:

    # Create keypair
    print( "Creating keypair...")
    resp = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName=keypair_name)
    private_key = resp["KeyMaterial"]

    # Delete old keyfile.
    print( "Writing key file...")
    try:
        os.unlink(secret_file)
    except:
        pass

    # Write new keypair to file.
    open(secret_file, "w").write(private_key)
    os.chmod(secret_file, 400)

    print("Written to %s." % secret_file)

############################################################################
# Workers
############################################################################

# In this step a stack of worker instances is created using CloudFormation.

# Check if stack exists.
print("*** Workers stack")
if stack_exists(cf, workers_name):
    print("Workers stack already exists.")
else:
    print("Creating workers stack...")

    # Create stack
    response = cf.create_stack(
        StackName=workers_name,
        TemplateURL=workers_template,
        Capabilities=["CAPABILITY_IAM"],
        Parameters=[
            {
                "ParameterKey": "ClusterName",
                "ParameterValue": cluster_name
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup",
                "ParameterValue": vpc_sg
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "NodeGroupName",
                "ParameterValue": cluster_name + "-worker-group"
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize",
                "ParameterValue": str(node_group_min)
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize",
                "ParameterValue": str(node_group_max)
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "NodeInstanceType",
                "ParameterValue": instance_type
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "NodeImageId",
                "ParameterValue": node_images[region]
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "KeyName",
                "ParameterValue": keypair_name
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "VpcId",
                "ParameterValue": vpc_id
            },
            {
                "ParameterKey": "Subnets",
                "ParameterValue": ",".join(vpc_subnet_ids)
            }
        ],
        TimeoutInMinutes=15,
        OnFailure='DELETE'
    )

    if response == None:
        print("Could not create worker group stack")
        sys.exit(1)

    if not "StackId" in response:
        print("Could not create worker group stack")
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Initiated workers (ETA 5-20 mins)...")

    print("Waiting for workers stack creation to complete...")

    try:
        # This is a water which waits for the stack deployment to complete.
        waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')
        res = waiter.wait(
            StackName=workers_name
        )
    except:
        print("Gave up waiting for stack to create")
        sys.exit(1)

    print( "Stack created")

# Get stack info.
stack = cf.describe_stacks(StackName=workers_name)
node_instance_role = None

# We need NodeInstanceRole output.
for v in stack["Stacks"][0]["Outputs"]:
    if v["OutputKey"] == "NodeInstanceRole": node_instance_role = v["OutputValue"]

print("Node instance role: %s" % node_instance_role)

############################################################################
# Introduce workers to master
############################################################################

# Final step is to deploy a config map which tells the master how to
# contact the workers.

print("*** Update worker auth")

# This is horrific.  Can't get K8s to use a file created by PyYAML.
config = "apiVersion: v1\nkind: ConfigMap\nmetadata:\n  name: aws-auth\n" + \
         "  namespace: kube-system\ndata:\n  mapRoles: |\n" + \
         "    - rolearn: " + node_instance_role + "\n" + \
         "      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}\n" + \
         "      groups:\n        - system:bootstrappers\n        - system:nodes\n"

print("Write config map...")

open(worker_auth, "w").write(config)

resp = subprocess.call(["kubectl", "--kubeconfig=%s" % config_file, "apply",
                        "-f", worker_auth])

if resp != 0:
    print("The kubectl command didn't work.")
    sys.exit(1)

print("Written.")

print("Try:")

print("  kubectl --kubeconfig=%s get nodes" % config_file)
```

Please let me know if there is something that could be done to resolve the issue.

Reference Link : https://github.com/cybermaggedon/aws-eks-deployment/blob/master/deploy-k8s

Comment: Well, you're only subprocess call is to kubectl, so that must be missing from your shell search path.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]: what's the minimum amount of code you need to run to demonstrate the error?  Do you need, for example, the "keypairs" block of code, or can it be deleted entirely and you'll still have the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652030/3514300 might help you.