# Write an Octave command line in Python and extract the outputs

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, octave

I am willing to call Octave from my python script without using the python package `oct2py` (I'm having troubles importing [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792257/problems-importing-the-oct2py-python-package?noredirect=1#comment116391074_65792257)). I am aware of the use of the `subprocess` package, but how can I extract the output of an Octave function from this command. I rephrase: say I have a function that computes the fft defined as follows:
`function [A,f]=fft_of_signal(Value,T)%coumputes A and f end`

Calling this from Octave goes as follows:
`octave:1> [v,f]=fft_of_signal(value,T)`.

How can I use `subprocess` to ask for the computed values of v and f?
`subprocess.run(['octave-cli.exe','[v,f]=fft_of_signal(value,T);'])`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont.

Instead, create an octave script which saves any desired outputs in a .mat file and then exits.

Then, open the .mat file from python using `scipy.io.loadmat`