# Why do I get the following error when I try to import oct2py?

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

The error occurs when I try to import the oct2py package. Here's my code:

```
import oct2py
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\samke\___\___\___\test.py", line 1, in <module>    # I blanked out the path for privacy
    import oct2py
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oct2py\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    octave = Oct2Py()
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.restart()
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\oct2py\core.py", line 533, in restart
    self._engine = OctaveEngine(stdin_handler=self._handle_stdin,
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.repl = self._create_repl()
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\octave_kernel\kernel.py", line 402, in _create_repl
    repl = REPLWrapper(cmd, orig_prompt, change_prompt,
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\metakernel\replwrap.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.child = pexpect.spawnu(cmd_or_spawn, echo=echo,
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\metakernel\pexpect.py", line 29, in spawn
    child = PopenSpawn(command, timeout=timeout, maxread=maxread,
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
PS C:\Users\samke\Dev\Trading_Program\ML>
```

If it helps, I'm running python 3.10.5.

Thanks all!

Edit: I do have octave installed, and octave is on my path, as the oct2py documentation says is necessary.

Comment: Do you have [Octave installed](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py#installation)? Edit the question.

Comment: I edited my question. I do have octave installed, and octave is on my path, as the oct2py documentation says is necessary.

Comment: Maybe give more details on the tools you're running this with? Like PyCharm or VS Code or the Python interpreter from the command line or what. Is this the only line of code you're executing?

Comment: How did you install Octave?  The error is confusing, because well before it gets to this point, the code checks to make sure that "octave.exe" is found.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application help? How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162989/jupyter-notebook-octave-kernel-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I spent half a day looking for a solution. Your problem might be similar to mine, so I will explain my situation and the solution, and hopefully, it will help solving your issue as well.

1. Download [octave-7.1.0-w64.zip](https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/octave/windows/octave-7.1.0-w64.zip) and extracted it
   under the path e.g.,  `C:\octave-7.1.0-w64`
2. Add `C:\octave-7.1.0-w64\mingw64\bin` to the environment variables.
   *(run: **edit environment variables for your account** and edit the path field there)*.
   The reason is that,  `octave.exe` is located in this path, and this what we need to run octave in the console mode.
3. Run the command prompt (CMD) and type `octave` *(i.e. calling octave.exe)*.
   At this point, I got an error message. And this what caused that error when calling octave from oct2py.
4. To fix this issue, go to the octave main  folder `C:\octave-7.1.0-w64` and run the script `post-install.bat`. This adds and updates octave packages.
5. Once the post install script is done,  run octave again from the command line *(step 3)*. If everything is done correctly, then octave console will start `octave:1>`. This indicates that octave is ready to be called from oct2py without any issue.
6. Run python and execute  `import oct2py`. It executed successfully.

I repeated the same procedure on two different devices and it works.