# Poetry on Windows in a batch file

Tags: python, windows, python-poetry

I am trying to write a script for starting my python app on windows. The app manages its dependencies using poetry. I tried a few things, including:

```
call "poetry" run pack_one/one.py
```

and

```
poetry run pack_one/one.py
```

However, I always get this error:

```
  OSError

  [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

  at ~\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.9\lib\subprocess.py:1207 in _execute_child
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do

`poetry run python /path/to/script`

`poetry run` tries to execute an executable inside the poetry venv (but not run a python script)

you could also do `poetry shell` first to enter the virtual env and then just `python /path/to/script`