# I am getting an error when using subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an issue running the file `hello.exe` from within a subprocess.run() command! The error is:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

And my code is:

```
def exit():
    os._exit(0)

def launchscript():
    subprocess.run("{}\hello.exe".format(cwd))
    exit()
```

Any help appreciated!

I tried:

```
def exit():
    os._exit(0)

def launchscript():
    subprocess.run("{os.getcwd()}\hello.exe") (obviously with os imported)
    exit()
```

Comment: You need an f-string for `"{os.getcwd()}\hello.exe"` to have `os.getcwd()` evaluated.

Comment: Beyond that, `subprocess.run()` is always relative to the working directory by default, so you don't _need_ to use `os.getcwd()` at all.

Comment: Also, you’ll need a forward slash as the path separator.

Comment: There's no `%1` anywhere in your code, I don't see how you're getting that error from this code.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe from `os` internals? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application#comment57056776_25652030