Selenium/webDriver don't run
Strangely a week ago the code started giving errors.
selenium=4.1.3  // windows 10
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver), chrome_options=chrome_options)

Error:
c:\Users\User\Desktop\text.py:14: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver), chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\text.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver), chrome_options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 non è un'applicazione di Win32 valida

What could it be?
I tried to update selenium or chromedriver

This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019720/13488161

This too, based simply on the windows error code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Windows 10 got an update today. Everything went back to working without doing anything.
