# Running a .py file in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, raspberry-pi2, pause

I am currently trying to run a `.py` file but in a loop.
Just for a test I am using

```
I = 0
while I<10:
    os.pause(10)
    open(home/Tyler/desktop/test.py)
    I = I + 1
```

I am sure this is a very simple question but I can't figure this one out. 
I would also like to add in the very end of this I have to make this run infinitely and let it run for some other things.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I would have to go back and look

Comment: When you post questions on StackOverflow it's usually helpful to include any errors you have to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: thank you for responding so fast by the way.

Comment: ill run back and look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your code isn't working:

1. Incorrect indentation (this may just be how you copied it on to StackOverflow though).
2. Using `os` without importing it.
3. Not using quotes for a string.
4. Mis-using the `open` function; `open` opens a file for reading and/or writing. To execute a file you probably want to use the `os.system`.

Here's a version that should work:

```
import os

i = 0
while i < 10:
    os.pause(10)
    os.system("home/Tyler/desktop/test.py")
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

- Python is indentation-sensitive, and your code is missing indentation
  after the `while` statement!
- Running the `open` command will not run the Python script.  You can
  read what it does here in the docs:
  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
- This stack overflow question talks about how to run Python that's
  stored in another file
  [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

  I recommend wrapping the code you want to run in a function, e.g.

  ```
   def foo():
       print 'hello'
  ```

  and then saving this in foo.py.  From your main script, you can then do:

  ```
  import foo

  i = 0
  while i < 10:
      foo.foo()
      i += 1
  ```
- If you want to run something in an infinite loop, you need the condition for the `while` loop to always be true:

  ```
  while True:
      # do thing forever
  ```
- **A note on importing:** The example I have given will work if the foo.py file is in the same directory as the main Python file.  If it is not, then you should have a read here about how to create Python modules http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Comment: I changed your variable I to i, as it is generally considered bad to have variables with capital letters in python, see the style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I was going to use this for two programs so also thank you for responding because you also fixed both of my problems

Comment: Thanks TylerTotally :)  Maybe you can give me an upvote if you liked my answer ;o

Comment: No problem! obviously I am very new to this judged by my repetition and my python programing ability. My "mother tongue" is JavaScript so this is all new waters

Comment: Good luck on your Python journey!  It's so much easier to read than JS in my opinion!  Just give yourself a little time :)