# running a python script trhough another python script raises an error

Tags: python

So I have this script that I need to develop that runs constantly and runs others scripts every month, and in case anything goes wrong I need it to send an email alert, as I was implmenting it I first tested this very simple piece of code

```
import datetime, time

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.strftime("%d") == '10':
        try:
            import download_ibama
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            
        time.sleep(86400)
```

the problem is, it runs the program perfectly as I want it, but it raises an exception telling me that there is no module named "download_ibama" how can I overcome it? cause the program did what I wanted it to do, I want it to raise an exception just in case it doesn't

P.S. "download_ibama" is the other script that i am calling, they're both in the same directory

Comment: That depends on your project structure, where `download_ibama` is located, etc...

Comment: Do you have a file called `download_ibama` created? And I think people need more context

Comment: it is the other script that I am calling, they're both in the same directory

Comment: try with `reload(download_ibama)` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload but its not a best way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a .py file in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998544/running-a-py-file-in-a-loop)