# How to execute a script from another one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a school project I need to know how to run a Python script from another one that's also written in Python (for the raspberry pi).

Comment: `subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'otherscript.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])`

Comment: I've just tried it but it does not work

Comment: vassili_veronesi: In that case, please [edit] your answer and add code showing what you tried that didn't work (and information on the errors encountered running it).

Comment: If the other script is in the same directory as the first one, you can simply `import` it as a module. For example, if the second script's filename was `second.py`, you would need to use `import second`.

Comment: You might want to check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another