# Calling two Python file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I have two python file both are pulling two different types of data,
My requirement is instead of running the two separate python file, I want a single python by which I can run both the python file one by one.
I don't want to make any changes to both the python file.

Suppose the name of both the file is abc.py and xyz.py

Comment: Why not use a bash or batch script to do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make one python file run another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: Sir I don't want to make any changes to my existing python script.
I want a separate python file through which i can call both the python file one by one.

Comment: Just copy one file and paste it to end of another. Or write a script to run both, one after another.

Comment: FancyDolphin the script you are talking about is different, as in that script 1 is somehow using in Script 2, so import will work, But I am asking to call two different script not related to each other just by calling a single script. In the new script I just have to give the path along with the script name and that script execute the named script one by one, not overlapping each other.

Comment: Prajwal 3: I have tried what you suggest but it will not work.
Better to give some example