# How to start a script from another script in python

Tags: python

I have created a script that checks if some other script is running

```
import os
import datetime
import time
from time import ctime

statinfo = os.stat('nemo_logs/nemo_log_file_' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.txt')
for i in range(1):
    first_size = statinfo.st_size
    time.sleep(10)
    if statinfo.st_size > first_size:
        print("SCRIPT IS RUNNING")
    else:
        print("SCRIPT IS NOT RUNNING. TRYING TO KILL THE SCRIPT...")
        os.system("pkill -9 -f selenium_nemo.py")
        print("SCRIPT KILLED. TRYING TO RESTART THE SCRIPT...")
        os.system("python selenium_nemo.py")
        print("SCRIPT STARTED")
```

If the script logs are increasing then we are OK, but if the script has stuck for some case i want to stop it and restart the script once more.
First i kill the script and then i'am executing `os.system("python selenium_nemo.py")` . The script starts but it runs inside my main script. How i can i start the `selenium_nemo.py` on another proccess?
'The for loop is for later'

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @SimonHibbs I believe this is what i'am looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` module for this. 
Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) for more.