# Python - How to invoke another .py file and use its return value

Tags: python, subprocess, return-value

How can I use return value in another file?

```
File1:
    def system(self):
        # do something
        return: value_1, value_2

File2:
    def to_do(self):
       # do something
       result = file_location.file1(value_1, value2)
```

Is this correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: Read [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) which comes installed with python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186847/9400024

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: Question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

You should import the specific method of `File1.py` in `File2.py` that you want to use.
Also note that python can return multiple values and how I have stored them in File2.py.

**File1.py**

```
    def system(self):
        # do something
        return value_1, value_2
```

**File2.py**

```
    from File1 import system
    def to_do(self):
       # do something
       result1, result2 = system(value_1, value2)
```