# Run script from GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, spyder

I wrote a script (test.py) for Data Analysis. Now I'm doing a GUI in PyQt.
What I want is when I press a button 'Run', the script test.py will run and show the results (plots).

I tried `subprocess.call('test1.py')` and `subprocess.Popen('test1.py')` but it only opens the script and don't run it.
I also tried `os.system`, doesn't work either.

The script below is not complete (there are more buttons and functions associated but is not relevant and aren't connect to the problem described).

I'm using Python 3.6 on Spyder and PyQt5.

Is there any other function or module that can do what I want?

```
class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEMP FILE")

        self.home()

    def home (self):
        btn_run = QPushButton("Run", self)
        btn_run.clicked.connect(self.execute)

        self.show()

    def execute(self):
        subprocess.Popen('test1.py', shell=True)
        subprocess.call(["python", "test1.py"])

if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

GUI = Window()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to capture and display the program's output?

Comment: Correct, display the program's output.

Comment: In future, I want that with GUI, I can choose the programs that I want to run. Is that also possible?

Comment: Sure, but we aren't just gonna write that code for you. Take a look at the [PyQt5 reference guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/).

Comment: Of course. For now I just tried several ways of doing this and I couldn't understand why it was not working. I'm checking that Guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a text label, then pipe stdout / stderr to [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    "python test1.py",
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Then call [`subprocess.Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
# Display stdout (and possibly stderr) in a text label
```

Comment: Still not working, probably I have some software issue, because if I paste the code directly in the GUI script it will run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can import test1.py and call functions from within it whenever you wish

Use this [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: Tried that too, but only works once. When I click a second time on button, the script won't run.

Comment: I suggest you add to your question the things you tried and the problems you had with each

Answer (score 0):

QProcess class is used to start external programs and to communicate with them.

Try it:

```
import sys
import subprocess

from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEMP FILE")
        self.home()

    def home (self):
        btn_run = QPushButton("Run", self)
        #btn_run.clicked.connect(self.execute)                                   # ---
        filepath = "python test1.py"                                             # +++
        btn_run.clicked.connect(lambda checked, arg=filepath: self.execute(arg)) # +++

        self.show()

    def execute(self, filepath):                                         # +++
        #subprocess.Popen('test1.py', shell=True)
        #subprocess.call(["python", "test1.py"])

        # It works
        #subprocess.run("python test1.py")

        QProcess.startDetached(filepath)                                 # +++



if not QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QApplication.instance()

GUI = Window()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Still not working, probably I have some software issue, because if I paste the code directly in the GUI script it will run perfectly.