# Python - How to call code from an external file

Tags: python, io, call

I have revised this question to make it much more simple.

I am running a program in ***python 3.x***.
I want this program to open a file name **example.py** and run the code inside it.
This is the contents of the file:

```
#example1.py
print('hello world')

#example2.py
    print('hello world 2')

#main.py
someMagicalCodeHere(executes example2.py)
#prints hello world
```

I need to do this without it being an imported file.

The problem with imported files is they are **declared beforehand** in the main.py. My main.py will be creating **example1.py, example2.py etc** and filling them with code, and then later referencing back to them as needed. There may be thousands or millions.

This is part of a large project that we are trying to switch over to a new language. We don't know python yet, and we need this concept to be viable to continue learning the language.

I have tried 
    exec(example.py)

I have tried
    with open('example.py', 'r') as ex:
         ex.read()

Thanks in advance for the answer, and thanks for all who have answered thus far.

Comment: Please also post your attempts for solving the problem. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after much deliberation, hunting and searching, I discovered through experimentation, found the answer to my own question.

```
#c:\\one.py
print('hello world')

#c:\\main.py
import os.path


filename = "c:\\one.py"

if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    print ('File does not exist.')
else:

    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in content:
        exec(line)
```

Returns (without quotes) 'Hello World'

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some kind of a function that converts strings to such answers, or perhaps a dictionary. Otherwise the solution to this problem would be beyond the scope of current progress in NLP.

`def ask_question_and_get_response(question=None):
    answer = input(question)
    return answer`

I must also assume that you have a way to convert the original question, such as *"What is your name?"*, to one that the user may in turn ask your bot, *"What is **my** name?"*. Let that function look like what follows:

```
def get_reflex_question(question):
    <your implementation>
    return reflex_question
```

With both of these in hand, we can create a file (if one doesn't already exist), and write what can be interpreted as Python code to it.

```
def make_code(answer, reflex_question)
    with open("filename", "a") as file:
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("if userBoxAsks == %s:\n\t" % (reflex_question))
        file.write("print(answer)")
```

Which will output code to a file of your naming.
To run that file, you could use the `subprocess` module (read documentation), or simply import this file of yours as a module itself.
Whenever you update the file, you could *reload* the import so that the new code runs too. In Python3.x, you can do `importlib.reload(filename)` to refresh the import.

Answer (score 0):

Note that these solutions are not secure and considered risky. So obviously meant for play/test purpose

**Python 2:**

```
execfile('example2.py')
```

**Python 3:**

```
with open('example2.py') as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

Comment: Only unsafe when exposed to unsafe things :) 
Being run on an non-connected machine.