# How to run a python program in a loop with different arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I am using *argparse* to pass arguments on the command line, while executing the program. There is one argument that I need to change every time I run the program. I was thinking of storing all the instances of that particular argument in a list and write a program that executes my python program,say `test.py` taking one instance of that list every time it runs.
python test.py --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2

List of instances of **arg2** : [a2_1,a2_2,a2_3].
I want to automate the process, such that the following gets executed:

```
python test.py --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2_1
```

followed by

```
python test.py --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2_2
```

then

```
python test.py --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2_3
```

automatically and I dont have to pass the next arguments manually every time one gets executed.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you able to edit the script to take a list of strings?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to clearly understand what u r saying

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `--arg2 a2_1,a2_2,a2_3`? And handling that internally to your script?

Answer (score 1):

If you really **want** to call your script from "command line", you may do something like that:

```
import os

args = [a2_1, a2_2, a2_3]
for arg in args:
  os.system("python test.py --arg1 {} --arg2 {}".format(a1, arg))
```

Make sure that a1 also initialized somewhere in the script.

I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) topic though, you might find that useful. Good luck!