# Running python scripts on apache server and get the output as http response

Tags: python, django, apache2

I have a django website hosted on raspberry pi using apache server.

Is there any way I can execute python scripts on the pi server and get the output of the scripts in the website?

I have link to all the python files on the website but when I click them instead of executing the raw code opens.

Comment: It sounds like your apache server is setup to just return the files in a directory when you browse to that directory's url. What you want is create a url pointing to a django view that executes the script chosen (which would be passed as a query parameter to the view). But you should show us your Django code and be more specific about your issue.

Comment: Yes this is true. But I don't know what should be written in that django view so that it can execute the script on server and return the result as httpresponse.

Comment: well hello, django is written in python and everything you run in a view is a python script. I don't understand the problem. If your python script defines a function, you just import it and run the function, passing the return value to a variable that you can then display in your template.

Comment: I need to run script that is on the server from the django view and get the output back.

Comment: That’s exactly what my previous comment answers, how does this not help?

Answer (score 0):

Aside that this is a very risky thing to do, you can do this in different ways - see these answers, where the second one also shows how to fetch the output:

[How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)