# Pass argument to python script using exec(open())

Tags: python

I am newbie in python programming and need your help.
I am running a python script using exec(open("./path to script/script.py").read()).
If I try to pass a argument then I always get the error the file doesnt exists, somehow the interpreter assumes that the string passed is the file name which is obviously not correct.

```
>>> exec(open("./path to script/script.py"  "hello").read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './path to script/script.pyhello'
```

Anybody has any tip on how to resolve this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you do really need to run scripts in such way? If so, read the documetation of [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec). `exec` function is for running python code represented as a string not a file. With exec you can "pass" parameters to you code with `globals` and  `locals` but it is not command line arguments. I suggest you to try [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to open a file and pass an argument as well, I'd advise you to use `os.system()` from the `os` module to achieve this as `exec()` does not provide you with that kind of functionality as you can only pass a string into it.
Example:

**Script.py:**

```
arg = input()
print(arg)
```

**Call to the above Script:**

```
import os

os.system('python3 home/pathtoscript/script.py Hello')
```

This will print the desired output for you on the terminal. But it also depends on what you  want to achieve further with it.

**Output:**

```
Hello
```

I'd also suggest using `argparse` module for dealing with arguments as it provides great support if you are trying your hand at multiple arguments. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) is the official documentation for the same.

Good Luck and Happy Coding.

Comment: Just as a note: the [documentation of `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) discourages the use of this function in favour of the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Specifically, [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is [recommended as a replacement for `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)

Comment: Sure does. `Subprocess` is the thing to go for. But for a newbie, I'd suggest `os.system` as it is a simple call to something that pritns on the terminal. I majorly suggest `subprocess` if the code is complex and expects a return from the script to be executed. I know I can be wrong, but I just wanted him to have a simple way to go through this and not get discouraged while using `subprocess`, as understanding how it works sure is a tough job.

Comment: I kind of disagree :) The fact that `os.system` only takes one argument does not make it simpler. You can use `subprocess.run` with a single string argument as well. In fact, `os.system` becomes more complicated once you go beyond simply fire & forget one command. But it's your answer, so you do you. If any interested reader decides to opt for `os.system` its fine by me, I just wanted to give them the option to at least consider `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.call`, hence my comment :)

Comment: @shmee Sir, you are absolutely correct. I'm just trying to help with the little knowledge I have, and this was the first answer that came to my mind. I'm subprocess has better calls and handles these scenarios better.

Comment: os.system commands runs into error with the import statement within my python script.

./script.py: line 2: import: command not found
./script.py: line 3: from: command not found

Comment: Also, please make edits to your question to make it visible. Commenting things wont make it easier for us to read

Comment: @DevanshuMisra, I am not sure how to add the new line, the comment is well framed but as soon as I finish editing it puts everything into one line.

Comment: Yes I understand. Please check the edits I made to my answer. You might have to specify `python` version and the full directory path to your script in order to run it. Also, which Python version are you using? Because the code i wrote for you is in Python3+ whereas seeing your traceback call, I assume you are using Python2 and hence the syntax error/command not found

Comment: Python version 2.7.14.    Content of the script.py file is below two lines
import sys
print sys.argv[1]

When I execute it using os.system I get following error.

>>> os.system('./script.py hi')
./script.py: line 1: import: command not found
./script.py: line 3: print: command not found

Comment: Did you import `os` in the other file where you are using os.system?? Also, send me a copy of both of your files on devanshumisra95@gmail.com. It'd be better if i see for myself. Ping/Comment here once you do

Comment: @PythonNewbie This looks like your system has no clue which interpreter to use for your script. Either use `python /path/to/script.py` (or `python2` or `python3`) in your `os.system`, as suggested by @DevanshuMisra in the answer, or make the script executable and add a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19305076/4134674) as the first line of your `script.py` file (assuming from the path you are on a Unix/Linux/Mac platform)

Comment: @shmee.. thanks for pointing the error.Thanks for all your help Devanshu.