# Run another Python script in different folder

Tags: python

How to run another python scripts in a different folder?

I have main program:
`calculation_control.py`

In the folder `calculation_folder`, there is `calculation.py`

How do I run `calculation_folder/calculation.py` from within `calculation_control.py`?

So far I have tried the following code:

```
calculation_file = folder_path + "calculation.py"
if not os.path.isfile(parser_file) :

    continue


subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, parser_file])
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to _import_ the module?

Comment: how to import from different folder ? , and i have calculation.py in several folder . and they have same variable and function. will it be a problem if i import all calculation.py to calculation_control.py ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Comment: First think about organising it in such way that you don't have multiple instances of the same file. Then think about having everything in the same folder. Then, if you are positive that you want multiple folders, configure the `PYTHONPATH` correctly so that python can find the modules in all folders you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: i think it is not duplicate , my problem is the another program in different folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> There are more than a few ways. I'll list them in order of inverted
>   preference (*i.e.*, best first, worst last):
>
> 1. **Treat it like a module:** `import file`. This is good because it's secure, fast, and maintainable. Code gets reused as it's supposed
>      to be done. Most Python libraries run using multiple methods stretched
>      over lots of files. Highly recommended. Note that if your file is
>      called `file.py`, your `import` should *not* include the `.py`
>      extension at the end.
> 2. **The infamous (and unsafe) [exec](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) command:** `execfile('file.py')`. Insecure, hacky, usually the wrong answer.
>      Avoid where possible.
> 3. **Spawn a shell process:** `os.system('python file.py')`. Use when desperate.
>
> Source: [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another/7975511#7975511)

**Solution**

Python only searches the current directory for the file(s) to import. However, you can work around this by adding the following code snippet to `calculation_control.py`...

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'calculation_folder') # Note: if this relavtive path doesn't work or produces errors try replacing it with an absolute path
import calculation
```

Comment: i think it doesnt work if the another python program in different folder

Comment: @Avic I have updated my answer to provide a solution at the end that should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: it doesnt work, but when i change relative path to absolut path ( D:/calc_system/calculation_folder  ) it works , thanks

Comment: oh i know , '/calculation_folder' , should be changed to 'calculation_folder' , and know it works

Comment: @Avic If you have found my answer helpful and/or a solution to your issue, please take a moment to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think `sys.path.insert(1, 'calculation_folder')` might be better. Then you make sure that `path[0]` is still the folder of the original file.