# How to write all file.sh into one sh file and let them run simultaneously?

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I have 15 python scripts need to be run. I know I can sbatch them one by one, but that's too tricky. Is there a way I put all of them in one file, and let them be executed them?

I'll add more detail.
Right now, i have 15 python files, which correspond to 15 .sh files. But i don't want to sbatch them one by one manually. So can i write a run.sh to put all the 15 .sh files into it, thereafter i only need do

```
sbatch run.sh
```

. Then all the work can be done.

Comment: I think you'll find a solution here : [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975511/10196815)

Comment: Did you check the unix cron job..This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question needs a bit more clarification. The question says simultaneously but then in the body you say one by one?

I do not know if this is exactly what you want, but you can try Python's `os.system(exe)` where exe would be the command you want to execute (e.g.: `python foo.py bar1 bar2`), and just have a Python script with all the executions.

Comment: If you think the question needs clarifications (and it does indeed) then ask for clarifications in a comment.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks, but how can i do  it?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry, I wanted to do so, but I do not have enough reputation. I tried giving an answer too, so it is not just a comment.

The files are Python scripts or Bash scripts?