# Trouble calling py script from another script

Tags: python, loadui

Im new to python, I created a py file from a ui file, the problem with that if i change something from the ui file nothing changes in py file therefore i made another py file that loads the ui file instead. With that if i change something in the ui file it also updates the py file. It is something like this.....

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

class Ui_DTR2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_DTR2,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('dtr.ui',self)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Ui_DTR2()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now my problem is that how can i call the above py script from another py script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reference you have some very well structured answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) which itself is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-script-from-another-script), which might make yours a duplicate also :)

In the .py script file simply import this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import youpreviousfile    #without .py
```

And the other example:

test1.py

> ```
> def some_func():
>     print 'in test 1, unproductive'
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     # test1.py executed as script
>     # do something
>     some_func()
> ```

service.py

> ```
> import test1
>
> def service_func():
>     print 'service func'
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     # service.py executed as script
>     # do something
>     service_func()
>     test1.some_func()
> ```