# Consecutively execute multiple python scripts

Tags: python, exec

I have several scripts that I wish to run consecutively (each saves their output as a file, so I don't need to look at them). I wish to create a separate python file that can run through them, executing each file once it is done with the previous. However, I am unsure how to execute one script from another.

I have created a sample subfile (script) to be run by another master file:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3))
x+=1
y=x**2
print(y)
```

This creates a couple matrices and does something with them. I include the print command as a test for whether it has run (perhaps this is not a good test?). The master file is below:

```
import os
os.system('python subfile_test.py')
# exec('sub_file')
```

I have tried using both the os.system() and exec() commands. When I use the os.system() command, I get no errors but I do not see the print, nor are the objects (x and y) accessible after running. When I comment out the first two lines and uncomment the exec() command, I get an error `NameError: name 'sub_file' is not defined`. I get the same error when I write 'sub_file.py' instead (adding the .py to the filename). Both files (master and sub) are located in the same folder, and this is the working directory (I am using Spyder).

I have referenced [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) and have tried the above methods. The preferred method (import) does not seem correct here, as I have no function/class I am importing - I just want to run a script.

What am I misunderstanding here, and can someone clarify under what situations each of these methods (import, os.system(), and exec()) are useful/not?

Comment: You're missing [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). `capture_output=True` should show you `print` outputs

Comment: It looks like subprocess is meant to replace os.system(). I am trying `subprocess.run('python sub_file.py', capture_output=True)` but this does not display the print output (although it may be running).