# Run a child python script and both display output (print and within-function displays) and access variables from child

Tags: python, parent-child

I have two files: parent.py and child.py. I wish to use the parent to run the child script, but I want the displays within the child script to appear in the console window. Example files are below:

child.py:

```
from scipy import optimize
x0=1

def f(x):
    return x**2

res = optimize.fmin(f, x0, disp=True)

print('print printed')
```

parent.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["python", "child.py"], capture_output=True)
```

My understanding was that the `capture_output` option should display the output as desired, but this does not appear to be the case. (This comes from the comment reply on my question [Consecutively execute multiple python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991448/consecutively-execute-multiple-python-scripts) which I am trying to ask here in a clearer way).

Both parent and child files are located within the same working directory, and I am using Spyder (not sure if that matters). I see what makes me think the child file is running `In: runfile('C:/.../parent.py', wdir='C:/.../testing')`, but I see neither the print() command nor the display from the optimize command displayed in my console. I also do not have access to the child variables once I have run the parent.

How do see the outputs (from print() and the optimize(.,disp=True) commands), as well as access the variables in the child script when running the parent?

Comment: Do you want the output of the child script to be *displayed* or to be *captured* for use by the parent script? (Note that you can't do both at once; the best you can do is to capture and re-display, possibly in real time if needed.)

Comment: If I can't do both, I have preference for displayed (so that I can see if the optimization gets hung up in one of the child scripts). However, it sounds like your option of the output being captured and re-displayed in real-time would be optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is to use the following line of code in the parent file:

```
exec(open('child.py').read())
```

This runs the file as desired, allows access to the variables created by the child file, and displays all desired output.

To give credit where deserved, I found the syntax described here: [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3) and this explains the reason my previous attempts at using exec() were incorrect.

Perhaps others can improve the answer by including alternatives to those concerned about insecurities related to exec().