# Is there a way to run a Python Script within another Python Script?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that needs to be crashes after 6 hours because the authorization expires. I want to write a Script that open and runs my original python script, closes it after 6 hours, and then reopens and runs it.

So basically a script that behaves like this

```
while true:
  run foo.py
```

foo.py, obviously is my original python script. foo.py runs completely before it loops.

I tried adding an if loop in the python script that reauthorizes when authorization expires but it wouldn't reauthorize. I need to close the script and reopen to authorize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Comment: That sounds like a really bad way to handle the authorization issue.

Comment: Can you not `import foo`, and write python code that calls other python code?

Comment: open(file, mode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: If you are on linux you can use [bash script](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting) And if you are on Windows you can take help of [batch script](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting)

Comment: I heard you like Python scripts, so I put a Python script in your Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers may tell you to use `execfile(file1.py)`. Don't do that.

The safest way is to simply import the other file:

```
import file1
```

or

```
from file1 import desired_function
```

Importing a file for the first time will run everything in that file not under `if __name__ == '__main__':`

You can then call `desired_function()` as many times as you want in `file2`.

Comment: Importing a module will run its contents the *first* time. Subsequent imports will just retrieve the existing module object.

Comment: This question is attempting to run a file repeatedly.

Comment: So you think os.system is a better answer? With the import can't you just import what you need from the other file and run that repeatedly?

Comment: If the other file were structured to allow that, that would be a better option, but it doesn't appear to be structured that way, and your answer treats `import` as a "run this file" command instead of showing how to run functions from an imported module.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell process:

```
import os

os.system('python file.py')
`
```