# Trying to make one python script run another?

Tags: python, windows

So I've seen lots of ideas that sort of answer this question, but in all solutions, it's the first script calling the other and running it itself. Is there a way to have one python script cause another script to run independently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: Use REST API call. Define HTTP endpoint using flask or any other framework. Call REST API Endpoint from one script. If you mean simply calling another script from python `exec(open("another.py").read());`

Comment: You can use `subprocess` in your current script like:   `import subprocess  
subprocess.call("other_script.py", shell=True)`

Comment: @NiranjhanaNarayanan, some systems either have a broken .py file association or default to opening in a text editor or IDE. I would first try `"py other_script.py"` and handle `FileNotFoundError` via `"python other_script.py"`. The py launcher tries to handle a shebang line in a script, given it needs a particular version or virtual environment. The fallback to "python" will probably use the current interpreter since `CreateProcess` searches the application directory first. Neither option needs or should use `shell=True`.