# How can I call another ".py" from this GUI in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, web-scraping, controls

I'm trying to call another py with a button in this GUI below. How can I create a button that calls another py?

The other py is in:
Y:\path\python_robos\Controle_teste.py

```
import tkinter
janela = tkinter.Tk()
janela.title("Controle dos Robôs - Mercado de Capitais / Diretoria de Securitização")

janela.geometry("1000x500+100+100")

lb = Label(janela, text = "Para rodar os robôs clique no botão abaixo.")
lb.place(x=10, y=20)

lb2 = Label(janela, text = "Robôs criados por Antonio Hildenberg com supervisão de Felipe Ribeiro. Set/2019")
lb2.place(x=10, y=470)

janela.mainloop()
```

can anydoby help me?
tks

Comment: Maybe this is what you want.
[How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the other Python file.

As an example if you have a python file named `constants.py`, in the same directory, you can import it by writing `import constants as const`.

You can now use its classes, methods and variables with `const.MY_CONSTANT`.

Edit:
Here's how you can create a button in tkinter and assign a click event listener to it.

```
"""Create Submit Button"""
submitButton = Button(master, command=self.buttonClick, text="Submit")
submitButton.grid()

def buttonClick(self):
    """ handle button click event and output text from entry area"""
    print('hello')    # do here whatever you want
    const.MY_METHOD(my_variable)
```

Comment: Tks @GeorgeWalt! but how can I call that py with a button in this Gui?

Comment: Check my latest edit for a coding example. Also you might want to take a look at the tkinter docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html