# How to run a python file, from another python file? (without waiting for it to close)

Tags: python

So im making a game in Pygame. Whenever player dies the program has to run another file and close itself.
for example:

```
import os 

os.system('python my_file.py')
quit(1)
```

but this method doesnt really work.
When it runs `my_file.py`  it waits for `my_file`  to close and then it runs `quit(1)` 
is there any way of making it work? (excluding `subprocess popen`  because i don'r really understand how it works

Comment: Why do you need to run a different python script? Can you not turn the other file into a module and import that into your code? That would be a lot cleaner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: I actually want to rerun this program but i cant have a main() or rerun() function without rebuilding the whole script/

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html this is most likely what do you want. Just pick first correct python version. Alternatively try multithreading.

Comment: Move your globals to some namespace ```function``` better ```class```, so they will stop being a singleton and you will be able to make a while loop for your ```start_game()``` function which will have default values on the next call

Comment: @AdamFeor yes, I mean kind of. When i run a python file using call `(["python", "your_file.py"])` it doesnt import pygame module.

Comment: i get ModuleNotFoundError even though i have it installed

Comment: Try using threading, it will quit while running the so. system code