# How can I make one python file ask for user input and then pass this input to a second .py file?

Tags: python, numpy, import, python-import

I have an analyze.py file that performs three steps:

1. it imports a .csv file as a numpy array;
2. it asks for user input 
   (e.g. `x=input ('Enter a number by which you want to multiply your array?')`
3. uses that input to perform some array operations 
   (e.g. `output_array=csv_array*x`).

After step 3, I would like to close the existing window and automatically run a second .py file which imports the new array (output_array).

In other words, I would like to pass a user-input variable from one py file to another. How can I do it?

Please note that I am aware of similar questions (e.g. [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)), but I cannot guess how to deal with user input.

Comment: Would it be a possibility to store the user output in a config file? That is how I have set up a similar project of mine. The second script extracts the necessary information from this file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this problem.

- **Use script args**
- **Write to file and read the same file**
- **Using message queues and workers (Much more complicated)**

I would suggest you go with the first approach and use arguments for the second script. You can call you script like this: `python script2.py arg1 arg2` and use `argsv` in the `script2` to read related arguments.

```sh
$ python script2.py arg1 arg2

>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.argv) # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `subprocess.run` to execute the second python file. This way you can pass the input array as argument to the second python file.

```py
from subrocess import run
command = []
command.append(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE_PATH)
command.append(SECOND_FILE_PATH)
command.append(array_converted_to_string) # e.g. separate array elements with dashes '-'
completed_process = run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

So three things for you to implement:

- a function to convert an array to a string
- a function to do the conversion back
- argument parsing in the second python file # standard library has the argparse module for that