# How to split two python files

Tags: python, tkinter, graph, split, window

I am having a little trouble with my serial port viewer. I have programmed a python file to read data from my COM port, which recieves them from my arduino board. The next file is an example code from this forum site (it is a real time graph plotter). Both codes are nice and easy to understand, but there is one fatal problem. First file - COM port reader uses library named tkinter and the second one pyqt5. I had no idea, how to split theese two files in one (to use only tkinter), but I have ascertained, that there is perhaps one solution: open the graph making file from the first one.

[How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

There is my trouble: I am not able to open it. I have used commands from the URL mentioned up and put them into marked place in the code. My terminal (when I start file converted to .exe says, that there is no file "modul1.py" in directory I have no idea, what is wrong...

Terminal.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolledtext
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import serial_rx_tx
import _thread
import time
import webbrowser
from tkinter import messagebox


# globals
serialPort = serial_rx_tx.SerialPort()
logFile = None
global str_message

root = tk.Tk() # create a Tk root window
root.title( "TERMINAL - Serial Data Terminal v1.01" )
# set up the window size and position
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
window_width = screen_width/2
window_height = screen_width/3
window_position_x = screen_width/2 - window_width/2
window_position_y = screen_height/2 - window_height/2
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, window_position_x, window_position_y))

# scrolled text box used to display the serial data
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='cyan')
frame.pack(side="bottom", fill='both', expand='no')
textbox = tkscrolledtext.ScrolledText(master=frame, wrap='word', width=180, height=28) #width=characters, height=lines
textbox.pack(side='bottom', fill='y', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
textbox.config(font="bold")

#COM Port label
label_comport = Label(root,width=10,height=2,text="COM Port:")
label_comport.place(x=10,y=26)
label_comport.config(font="bold")

#COM Port entry box
comport_edit = Entry(root,width=10)
comport_edit.place(x=100,y=36)
comport_edit.config(font="bold")
comport_edit.insert(END,"COM7")

# serial data callback function
def OnReceiveSerialData(message):
    global str_message
    str_message = message.decode("utf-8")
    textbox.insert('1.0', str_message)

def Dataprint():
    str_message


# Register the callback above with the serial port object
serialPort.RegisterReceiveCallback(OnReceiveSerialData)

def sdterm_main():
    root.after(200, sdterm_main)  # run the main loop once each 200 ms

#
#  commands associated with button presses
#
def OpenCommand():
    if button_openclose.cget("text") == 'Open COM Port':
        comport = comport_edit.get()
        baudrate = baudrate_edit.get()
        serialPort.Open(comport,baudrate)
        button_openclose.config(text='Close COM Port')
        textbox.insert('1.0', "COM Port Opened\r\n")
    elif button_openclose.cget("text") == 'Close COM Port':
        if button_replaylog.cget('text') == 'Stop Replay Log':
            textbox.insert('1.0',"Stop Log Replay first\r\n")
        else:
            serialPort.Close()
            button_openclose.config(text='Open COM Port')
            textbox.insert('1.0',"COM Port Closed\r\n")


def ClearDataCommand():
    textbox.delete('1.0',END)

def SendDataCommand():
    message = senddata_edit.get()
    if serialPort.IsOpen():
        message += '\r\n'
        serialPort.Send(message)
        textbox.insert('1.0',message)
    else:
        textbox.insert('1.0', "Not sent - COM port is closed\r\n")

def ReplayLogFile():
    try:
      if logFile != None:
        readline = logFile.readline()
        global serialPort
        serialPort.Send(readline)
    except:
      print("Exception in ReplayLogFile()")

def ReplayLogThread():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        global logFile
        if serialPort.IsOpen():
            if logFile != None:
                ReplayLogFile()

def OpenLogFile():
    if not serialPort.IsOpen():
        textbox.insert('1.0', "Open COM port first\r\n")
    else:
        if button_replaylog.cget('text') == 'Replay Log':
            try:
                root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                                           filetypes=(("log files", "*.log"), ("all files", "*.*")))
                global logFile
                logFile = open(root.filename,'r')
                _thread.start_new_thread(ReplayLogThread, ())
                button_replaylog.config(text='Stop Log Replay')
                textbox.insert('1.0', "Sending to open COM port from: " + root.filename + "\r\n")
            except:
                textbox.insert('1.0', "Could not open log file\r\n")
        else:
            button_replaylog.config(text='Replay Log')
            textbox.insert('1.0', "Stopped sending messages to open COM port\r\n")
            logFile = None


def DisplayAbout():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("About")

def TutorialsWebPage():
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("www.gykovysat.cz")

def Openport():
    execfile('modul1.py')

# COM Port open/close button
button_openclose = Button(root,text="Open COM Port",width=20,command=OpenCommand)
button_openclose.config(font="bold")
button_openclose.place(x=210,y=30)

#Clear Rx Data button
button_cleardata = Button(root,text="Clear Rx Data",width=20,command=ClearDataCommand)
button_cleardata.config(font="bold")
button_cleardata.place(x=210,y=72)

#Send Message button
button_senddata = Button(root,text="Send Message",width=20,command=SendDataCommand)
button_senddata.config(font="bold")
button_senddata.place(x=420,y=72)

#Replay Log button
button_replaylog = Button(root,text="Replay Log",width=20,command=OpenLogFile)
button_replaylog.config(font="bold")
button_replaylog.place(x=420,y=30)

#About button
button_about = Button(root,text="About",width=16,command=DisplayAbout)
button_about.config(font="bold")
button_about.place(x=620,y=30)

#Tutorials
button_tutorials = Button(root,text="Tutorials",width=16,command=execfile('modul1.py'))
#
#
#
#
#               !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!UP HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
button_tutorials.config(font="bold")
button_tutorials.place(x=780,y=30)

#
# data entry labels and entry boxes
#

#Send Data entry box
senddata_edit = Entry(root,width=34)
senddata_edit.place(x=620,y=78)
senddata_edit.config(font="bold")
senddata_edit.insert(END,"Message")

#Baud Rate label
label_baud = Label(root,width=10,height=2,text="Baud Rate:")
label_baud.place(x=10,y=70)
label_baud.config(font="bold")

#Baud Rate entry box
baudrate_edit = Entry(root,width=10)
baudrate_edit.place(x=100,y=80)
baudrate_edit.config(font="bold")
baudrate_edit.insert(END,"9600")

#
# The main loop
#
root.after(200, sdterm_main)
root.mainloop()
#
```

Modul1.py

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import functools
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from matplotlib.figure import Figure    
from matplotlib.animation import TimedAnimation
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import time
import threading
import serial_rx_tx
from terminal import Dataprint

class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # Define the geometry of the main window
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("my first window")
        # Create FRAME_A
        self.FRAME_A = QFrame(self)
        self.FRAME_A.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % QColor(210,210,235,255).name())
        self.LAYOUT_A = QGridLayout()
        self.FRAME_A.setLayout(self.LAYOUT_A)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FRAME_A)
        # Place the zoom button
        self.zoomBtn = QPushButton(text = 'zoom')
        self.zoomBtn.setFixedSize(100, 50)
        self.zoomBtn.clicked.connect(self.zoomBtnAction)
        self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.zoomBtn, *(0,0))
        # Place the matplotlib figure
        self.myFig = CustomFigCanvas()
        self.LAYOUT_A.addWidget(self.myFig, *(0,1))
        # Add the callbackfunc to ..
        myDataLoop = threading.Thread(name = 'myDataLoop', target = dataSendLoop, daemon = True, args = (self.addData_callbackFunc,))
        myDataLoop.start()
        self.show()
        return

    def zoomBtnAction(self):
        print("zoom in")
        self.myFig.zoomIn(5)
        return

    def addData_callbackFunc(self, value):
        # print("Add data: " + str(value))
        self.myFig.addData(value)
        return

''' End Class '''


class CustomFigCanvas(FigureCanvas, TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        self.addedData = []
        print(matplotlib.__version__)
        # The data
        self.xlim = 200
        self.n = np.linspace(0, self.xlim - 1, self.xlim)
        a = []
        b = []
        a.append(2.0)
        a.append(4.0)
        a.append(2.0)
        b.append(4.0)
        b.append(3.0)
        b.append(4.0)
        self.y = (self.n * 0.0) + 50
        # The window
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        # self.ax1 settings
        self.ax1.set_xlabel('time')
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('raw data')
        self.line1 = Line2D([], [], color='blue')
        self.line1_tail = Line2D([], [], color='red', linewidth=2)
        self.line1_head = Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='o', markeredgecolor='r')
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_tail)
        self.ax1.add_line(self.line1_head)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.xlim - 1)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        TimedAnimation.__init__(self, self.fig, interval = 50, blit = True)
        return

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return iter(range(self.n.size))

    def _init_draw(self):
        lines = [self.line1, self.line1_tail, self.line1_head]
        for l in lines:
            l.set_data([], [])
        return

    def addData(self, value):
        self.addedData.append(value)
        return

    def zoomIn(self, value):
        bottom = self.ax1.get_ylim()[0]
        top = self.ax1.get_ylim()[1]
        bottom += value
        top -= value
        self.ax1.set_ylim(bottom,top)
        self.draw()
        return

    def _step(self, *args):
        # Extends the _step() method for the TimedAnimation class.
        try:
            TimedAnimation._step(self, *args)
        except Exception as e:
            self.abc += 1
            print(str(self.abc))
            TimedAnimation._stop(self)
            pass
        return

    def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
        margin = 2
        while(len(self.addedData) > 0):
            self.y = np.roll(self.y, -1)
            self.y[-1] = self.addedData[0]
            del(self.addedData[0])

        self.line1.set_data(self.n[ 0 : self.n.size - margin ], self.y[ 0 : self.n.size - margin ])
        self.line1_tail.set_data(np.append(self.n[-10:-1 - margin], self.n[-1 - margin]), np.append(self.y[-10:-1 - margin], self.y[-1 - margin]))
        self.line1_head.set_data(self.n[-1 - margin], self.y[-1 - margin])
        self._drawn_artists = [self.line1, self.line1_tail, self.line1_head]
        return

''' End Class '''


# You need to setup a signal slot mechanism, to
# send data to your GUI in a thread-safe way.
# Believe me, if you don't do this right, things
# go very very wrong..
class Communicate(QObject):
    data_signal = pyqtSignal(float)

''' End Class '''



def dataSendLoop(addData_callbackFunc):
    # Setup the signal-slot mechanism.
    mySrc = Communicate()
    mySrc.data_signal.connect(addData_callbackFunc)

    # Simulate some data
    n = np.linspace(0, 499, 500)
    y = Dataprint()
    i = 0

    while(True):
        if(i > 499):
            i = 0
        time.sleep(0.1)
        mySrc.data_signal.emit(y[i]) # <- Here you emit a signal!
        i += 1
    ###
###

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. The parentheses around if statements and loops are unnecessary, this isn’t Java.

Comment: Also asterisk imports are a bad idea.

Comment: It's difficult for you to separate out the pyqt5 elements because they've come from `*` imports. This is a bad idea because, as you've seen, you can't see what came from where

Comment: I think you should start with just reading from the COM port. This appears to be doing too much, you've tried to weave together two standalone solutions. Shoot for the visualization last, and simply try to read some data

Comment: You think like put in graph code something like code mentioned down?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code might help you to help me answer my question. (It is a raw code for reading COM port.)

```
import serial
import sys
import _thread


class SerialPort:
    def __init__(self):
        self.comportName = ""
        self.baud = 0
        self.timeout = None
        self.ReceiveCallback = None
        self.isopen = False
        self.receivedMessage = None
        self.serialport = serial.Serial()

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            if self.serialport.is_open():
                self.serialport.close()
        except:
            print("Destructor error closing COM port: ", sys.exc_info()[0] )

    def RegisterReceiveCallback(self,aReceiveCallback):
        self.ReceiveCallback = aReceiveCallback
        try:
            _thread.start_new_thread(self.SerialReadlineThread, ())
        except:
            print("Error starting Read thread: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

    def SerialReadlineThread(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.isopen:
                    self.receivedMessage = self.serialport.readline()
                    if self.receivedMessage != "":
                        self.ReceiveCallback(self.receivedMessage)
            except:
                print("Error reading COM port: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

    def IsOpen(self):
        return self.isopen

    def Open(self,portname,baudrate):
        if not self.isopen:
            # serialPort = 'portname', baudrate, bytesize = 8, parity = 'N', stopbits = 1, timeout = None, xonxoff = 0, rtscts = 0)
            self.serialport.port = portname
            self.serialport.baudrate = baudrate
            try:
                self.serialport.open()
                self.isopen = True
            except:
                print("Error opening COM port: ", sys.exc_info()[0])


    def Close(self):
        if self.isopen:
            try:
                self.serialport.close()
                self.isopen = False
            except:
                print("Close error closing COM port: ", sys.exc_info()[0])

    def Send(self,message):
        if self.isopen:
            try:
                # Ensure that the end of the message has both \r and \n, not just one or the other
                newmessage = message.strip()
                newmessage += '\r\n'
                self.serialport.write(newmessage.encode('utf-8'))
            except:
                print("Error sending message: ", sys.exc_info()[0] )
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False
```