# Is there a way to have a python script replace a new file with old

Tags: python

I am a newbie python developer and I have a question.
I have a python script check if updates are available on an external webpage but I got stuck while trying to get it to override old file with new one. What the code does below is get new.py and open it as a txt file. It then searches for `__VERSION__`. My code for searching for new version is below. How would I replace current.py with new.py?

```
__VERSION__ = '1.0'
#Get new version
new_version = ''
with open('new.py') as newfile:
    for line in newfile:
        line = line.strip()
        if '__VERSION__' in line:
            _, new_version = line.split('=', maxsplit=1)
            new_version = new_version.strip()
            break
```

Thanks @user:6530979
Can anyone help me understand what to do after this?
EDIT: The goal is for current.py to override its self with new.py’s code
**Any help will be appreciated!!**

Comment: Is the code sample you include above a part of `current.py`? In other words, is the goal to have `current.py` overwrite itself?

Comment: Yes this is the goal.

Comment: what's wrong with checking each line if ____VERSION____ is in it and then replace it, and write that new line to the file? basically first read the entire file and save it in a list with readlines. then check each line in the file by iterating over the list and replace ____VERSION____ with what you want? and then after that just write the list to the file

Comment: Can you provide a code example so I can fully understand what you mean because I am not sure what you are getting at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, these solutions are hacky at best-- no guarantees.

You SHOULD look into package management/version control, because the systems already developed to do this are likely to be much more reliable.

BUT, you might be able to use `os.rename`. I'm not sure if this is a *good* solution, or how safe it is, but it worked in my quick trial.

```py
''' current.py (V1) '''
import os

os.rename("current.py", "old.py")
os.rename("new.py", "current.py")
```

In this case, `current.py (V1)` is the file run by the user. After execution, you are left with `old.py` and `current.py (V2)`.

Two things to note:

1. You won't have line-by-line control via this method.
2. You might want to make this program call another (like V1 calling V2 and then exiting), using strategies such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975511/11639533).

Answer (score 1):

```
# what you want to replace '__VERSION__' with
replace = 'what ever you want'
new_lines = []
with open('new.py',"r") as newfile:
    lines = newfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        new_lines.append(line.replace("__VERSION__", replace))


with open('new.py',"w") as newfile2:
    full_file_text = "".join(new_lines)
    newfile2.write(full_file_text)
```

is this what you wanted? to replace some text in a specific line?

Comment: @Pythondoit well I hope this helped.