# How to run one python file in another file?

Tags: python, file, module, package

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('file.py')
error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file.py'; 'file' is not a package
```

Is this a good way of running one file in another? If not, could you please tell me a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With ".py" it is the file, without it is the module.

Comment: This post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: @MichaelButscher I want to run a file in another file. When I put '.py' the above error occurs. Could you give an alternative or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import it as a module you should listen to the comments and do what they say (visit [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)).
But if for some reason which I don't understand you wanted to run it as an independent file and not a module you could do the following:

```
import os
os.system('python3 yourPythonFile.py')
```

However, I think that this isn't a good practice as it blocks the main script until "yourPythonFile.py" stops running.