# How can I use a Python file to execute terminal command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, all I want is opening a Python script with a Python script? I want  the equivalent of 'Python script.py'. Can someone explain how can I execute a. py file. How can I use subprocess to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Import and run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Answer (score 0):

With the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python', 'script.py'])
```

If you want to use the same python as the caller you can do:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'script.py'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways:**

```
subprocess.call(command)
subprocess.check_call(command)
subprocess.check_output(command)
subprocess.run(command)
os.system(command)
```

(Each of them has it's own features and you can search in SO to find their differences.
I usually use `os.system(command)`)

Also I found [THIS](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.execl): **os.exec***** are realy helpful in these situations