# Execute python terminal commands in a python script file

Tags: python, terminal, object-detection

So, I am using a python file to run object detection on an image. I want to run this file inside a python script and save the output from a .py file.

```
python3 yolo_video.py --model='models.h5' --classes='_classes.txt' --image --input='pic1.jpeg' --output='obj_det
```

So, I need the output in a Python file. I put an exclamation mark because that is what happens in the jupyter notebook. How do I run it in the script? I don't want to change function in the yolo_video.py file.

```
python output = !python3 yolo_video.py --model='models.h5' --classes='_classes.txt' --image --input='pic1.jpeg' --output='obj_det
```

Comment: [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7974849/7665043) -- using Python to run Python. Also, shells can generally do `> file.ext` to redirect the output of a command to a file.

Comment: The `subprocess` module lets you run external programs. Likely `subprocess.run` will work for you.