# How to resolve the FileNotFound when using os.execv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble using `os.execv()` in Python.

I have a file called `test-exec.py` that should call another file called `helloworld.py` (this file should just print hello world). I want the `test-exec.py` to run `helloworld.py`

`test-exec.py` looks like the below:

```
import sys
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
   os.execv("usr/bin/python3", ['helloworld.py'])
```

when running [the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cc0V.png) with the command `python3 test-exec.py helloworld.py` (the `helloworld.py` is unnecessary right now) I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

but the file `helloworld.py` is in the directory:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYXfW.png)

I'm using a virtual machine if that helps any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/usr/bin/python3`? (missing one slash in the start...)

Answer (score 0):

You can just go with the `os.system()` command. Try using something like this:

If they are in the same directory:

```
os.system("python3 helloworld.py")
```

Or if they are not in the same directory:

```
os.system("python3 path/to/the/file.py")
```