# How to execute another Python file from current script?

Tags: python

So I have a login script called `login.py`. When user log in, script will create a user session and execute `main.py` and close `login.py`. How to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Comment: Run in the same console or a different console? By "close login.py" you infer run in a different console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you need help with but try this:

```
from fileName import function_you_want
```

Ideally you don't want a script to run on an import. It can cause some unexpected things to happen. At the bottom of main.py I would use this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     call_your_function()
```

This way you can do tests by running the script directly or calling a specific method from another py file without running the script.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is import that file `main.py` like `import main`. If you want everything from that file, `from main import *`

Then, after the user logins, destroy your main window using `<Tk>.destroy()` and then call your function.