# im trying to make a script in python thats takes the users input and runs a file depending on that input

Tags: python

How do I make this work? I tried looking in websites, but to no avail, I need this to work because I want to use it instead of running the files separately, so can anyone help me with this code?

I need to know what is wrong here.

```
input=("input 1 for encoder and 2 for decoder: ")
if input=1 open encoder.py
if input=2 open decoder.py
```

edit: this question is different and not a duplicate because this question was asking on how to run a python script based on the user input, e.g. user inputs 1 then python script encoder is ran

```
if option == "1":
    import encoder
elif option == "2":
    import decoder
```

code is from sr0812
it is a different implementation here

Comment: Take a look at this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another

Comment: it not the same implementation

Comment: this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another is different because it's about running a python script automatically but my question is asking on how to make a python script run different scripts based on the user's input eg input = 1 it will run encoder.py but if its input = 2 it runs decoder.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this -

Method 1 -

```
import encoder
```

Note - this only works once in the entire program

Method 2 -

```
exec(open('decoder.py').read())
```

Note - this is unsafe and you should avoid when possible

Method 3 -

```
os.system('python file.py')
```

Note - this is very hacky and you shouldn't use it much

So this should be the solution you are looking for -

```
import os

option = input("input 1 for encoder and 2 for decoder: ")
if option == "1":
    import encoder
elif option == "2":
    import decoder
```

Source - [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)

Comment: its for this https://replit.com/@moongazer07/rickgenere

Comment: Does my edit solve your problem

Comment: yes it did solve the problem

Comment: by the way i put this in the code:  print("credit goes to sr0812 on stackoverflow for the menu code")

Comment: your Wellcome and by the way you can check the project I needed the code for here
https://replit.com/@moongazer07/rickgenere?v=1

Comment: A better approach would be to import the files once at the start of the file and call a respective function

Comment: Also you just repeated the answer from the linked question. Please flag the question as duplicate instead of duplicating answers...

Comment: Ok i have flagged the question