# How to import variable values from one python script to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three python scripts `START.py`, `credentials.py` and `ask_LDAP.py`. The first is in the `Szperacz_2.0` directory, which is the `root directory` for the rest, the next two are in the `src` directory, one level down.

```
Szperacz_2.0
|
| START.py
|- src
|   | - credentials.py
|   | - ask_LDAP.py
```

When I run `ask_LDAP.py` everything works and the console asks for `login` and `password` and then prints the entered characters. The problem is when I run `START.py`, the console asks for `login` and `password` and then returns an `error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Szperacz_2.0\START.py", line 10, in <module>
    import credentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'credentials'
```

I apologize in advance if the problem is trivial but I am a beginner in python.

my scripts:

`./START.py`

```
import os

# --- Clearing the Screen
os.system('cls')

path = "./src/credentials.py"
exec(open(path).read())

path = "./src/ask_LDAP.py"
import credentials
exec(open(path).read())
```

`./src/credentials.py`

```
import getpass
login = input("Login: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
```

`./src/ask_LDAP.py`

```
import credentials

login = credentials.login
password = credentials.password

print("login from credentials.py: " + login)
print("passwd from credentials.py: " +password)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not know what you mean by "credentials", since the file is not in the same directory. You can add a file named

```
__init__.py
```

to in your directory "src", therefore making it a package. Then you can modify your import in START.py to

```
from src import credentials
```

which should yield the desired result. Subsequently you will run into another error, due to the call to exec(). You should remove this part and use a better way as in:  [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another)