# How to pass arguments in python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, command, parameter-passing

I want to create a method which executes below command in python using `subprocess.run()`

```py
python3 detect_wrong.py --source overpass.mp4 --weights ./my_coco.pt --data ./data/my_coco.yaml

subprocess.run(["python","detect_wrong.py"])
```

I am stuck in this step. I want to know how to pass those arguments.

Comment: `detect_wrong.py` is an argument for `python`, so you were already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, you can add in the array every argument you would normally pass in a command-line.

For example, if you wanted to run `ls -l --color=auto`, you could write:

```py
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "--color=auto"])
```

Here, that would be:

```py
subprocess.run(["python3", "detect_wrong.py", "--source", "overpass.mp4", "--weights", "./my_coco.pt", "--data", "./data/my_coco.yaml"])
```

However, since you want to run a Python script from Python, I suggest you take a look here: [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another) and, as said there, treat `detect_wrong.py` as a module, if possible.
Else, you can run it with `exec()` or, if desperate, with `os.system()` or `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass arguments as entities on the list, like that:

```
subprocess.run(["python", "--argument=value", "detect_wrong.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

simply append arguments in the list of subprocess.run

```
subprocess.run(["python","detect_wrong.py","--source=overpass.mp4", "--weights=./my_coco.pt", "--data=./data/my_coco.yaml"])
```