# Python3 - runpy.run_path not working on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: python-3.x

I have code like this:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_path('other.py', globals())
```

It works on my Windows Box with Python 3.2 but fails on the default Python3 installation (from the Repository) on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/markus/Documents/projects/BlenderSerialize/generate.py", line 2, in <module>
    runpy.run_path('other.py', globals())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'
```

I checked the documentation and it says that run_path was introduced in Python 2.7. What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating Python3 is not an option there is a workaround that allows one to execute a python script.

The following python code works quite well for me:

```
exec(compile(open("somefile.py").read(), "somefile.py", 'exec'), local_vars, global_vars)
```

Other examples can be found in [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0)

Answer (score 1):

It was introduced in Python 2.7 and 3.2. Hence it will not work with Python 3.0 or 3.1. To make it work, use Python 2.7 or 3.2.

Comment: Is there a workaround that does not imply using a different Python verison?

Comment: @trenki: You can try and backport it in a separate module, but switching to Python 3.2 is honestly less work.