# Python - does an object with no references get destroyed automatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given this example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = [1, 2]
```

Does the previous object that x is pointing to, the array of 1, 2, and 3, get destroyed by the garbage collector of Python? Or does it float around with nothing pointing at it?

Comment: I believe it's garbage collected

Comment: Yes, it is garbage collected. However, exactly when the GC is triggered is unknown

Comment: As far as I understand [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9449506/6614295), this is actually implementation dependent and not guaranteed to be collected at all. It will probably be gc'ed, though.