# Python Nested Object Destructor (vs C++)

Tags: python, pointers, destructor

Let's say I have two classes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = SomeStuff()
        self.B = plt.figure(1)
    def SomeOtherThings(self):
        MaybeIPlotSomeThingsToThatPlotEtc
        ....

class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.AClassWithinAClass = AClass()
        self.B = plt.figure(2)
    def SomeOtherThings(self):
        MaybeIPlotSomeThingsToThatPlotEtc
        ....
```

In C++, when I put an object into another object as a POINTER to that object, I have to, HAVE to delete it in a destructor or it is a memory leak.

Question 1: In the above pseudocode, is self.B the kind of pointer that I need to delete in a destructor?

Question 2: What about the variable AClassWithinAClass? Is that a pointer that I need to delete in a destructor, or does python know to get rid of it when the AnotherClass gets deleted?

I've tried googling about pointers and stuff ([Pointers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106689/pointers-in-python)) but I guess I'm nervous because python is such an implicit language.

Comment: No. There are no pointers in Python, and memory is managed for you.

Comment: And if by destructor you are referring to `__del__` the **don't implement it** because messing with that could very well lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In both of these cases you do not need to explicitly call a destructor method.  Python uses garbage collection to manage memory. To maintain this it uses reference counting.  Python will keep a count of how many variables reference a particular object.  However, if Python has a variable that is not referenced by anything it will free the memory.  I'm certainly not an expert on the internal memory management of Python but that's my understanding.

[Previous StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449489/when-are-objects-garbage-collected-in-python)