# How to get the equivalent file size of a json object in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, size

I am writing a python object with `json.dump`.

But I want to only write objects that would not exceed 10KB file size.

How can estimate the size of an object before writing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it.

We start with the following sample (taken from [here](http://www.json.org/example.html), with a little extra added to make it interesting):

```py
sample_orig = """{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "a little extra" : "∫ßåøπœ®†"
}"""
```

Next, we define a test function to perform the encoding and output the size:

```py
def encode_sample(sample : str):
    for encoding in ('ascii', 'utf8', 'utf16'):
        filename = f'{encoding}.json'
        encoded_sample = sample.encode(encoding=encoding, errors='replace')
        with FileIO(filename, mode='wb') as f:
            f.write(encoded_sample)
            assert len(encoded_sample) == f.tell()
            print(f'{encoding}: {f.tell()} bytes')
```

The `assert` will prove that the size reported by `len` is the same **if we're dealing with a `bytes`** (not `str`). If not, the call will raise `AssertionError`.

We'll encode the original sample first:

```py
encode_sample(sample_orig)
```

Output:

```
ascii: 617 bytes
utf8: 627 bytes
utf16: 1236 bytes
```

Next, we run it through `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()` to "optimise" the size (i.e. remove unnecessary whitespace):

```py
sample_reduced = json.dumps(json.loads(sample_orig))
encode_sample(sample_reduced)
```

Output:

```
ascii: 455 bytes
utf8: 455 bytes
utf16: 912 bytes
```

Remarks:

- The OP asked "*[…] writing a python object with json.dump*", so the "optimisation" by removing whitespace doesn't really matter, but I left it in as it might benefit others.
- Encoding matters. `ascii` and `utf8` (the default) will result in the same filesize, if the output only contains ASCII characters. Because I added a little extra at the end of the JSON, the file sizes for both encodings differ. And `utf16` will of course be the largest of the three.
- As stated before, you can use `len` to get the size of the object if you encode it first.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the JSON to a string, then use [sys.getsizeof()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof). It returns the size in bytes, so you can divide by `1024` if you want to compare it to a threshold value in kilobytes.

```py
sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(object))
```

Sample usage:

```py
import json
import sys
x = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(y))) # 89
```

Edit:
As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901167) thread, objects have a higher size in memory. So subtract `49` from the size to get a better estimate.

```py
print(sys.getsizeof(json.dumps(y)) - sys.getsizeof(""))
```

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` tells you the size of the object in memory which is not the same as its file size.

Comment: @martineau you're right, added documentation and fixed it

Comment: My point is that `getsizeof()` has no bearing on the problem (so doesn't need to be used). The correct way to do this is to use `len(json.dumps(obj))`.