# NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined trying to run an app on Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[image: Google App Engine Launcher]

I get this error in windows, I have both 3.2 and 2.7 versions of python. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also, the following might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257243/error-in-running-google-apps-in-python-in-windows-os/36109549#36109549

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[image: solution]

You just need to go to edit/preferences and specify correct version of python path

Comment: Just a reminder, you have to use Python27, this doesn't seem to work with anything newer. Windows binaries are here: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/#id5.

Comment: Confirm, had to install Python 2.7.4 because 3.3.1 throws an error.

Comment: For users who need to stick with 3.x versions, I'd recommend checking out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0).

Comment: Lol, just tried to deploy a sample app and the hell is come. Version 2.7 is still at download index :D https://www.python.org/downloads/ Im sure there's a lot of compatability problems between versions. @jonathanconway thx for the links and the tip.

Comment: How about `C:\Python27\python.exe`? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I had python 27 and 34 installed in my system. You just have to change the path from python 34 to 27