# Google App Engine Launcher demo application not working

Tags: google-app-engine

I installed Google App Engine. When I File->Add Demo Application->python->guestbook, and try to run it, a yellow triangle appears with an exclamation mark. I get this error message also:

> 2015-07-26 22:36:10 Running command: "['C:\Python34\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\Users\Blackstorm\Documents\guestbook-1']"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
>       execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
>   NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
>   2015-07-26 22:36:11 (Process exited with code 1)

I think it should use Python 2.7 that I have installed. Why does it talk about Python 3.4? I have the path to python 2.7 in path system variable. I'm using Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify path to Python 2.7 in GAE Launcher's settings (Edit -> Preferences). Take a look at this question for more details: [NameError: global name 'execfile' is not defined trying to run an app on Google App Engine Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227142/nameerror-global-name-execfile-is-not-defined-trying-to-run-an-app-on-google)